# I'm getting a parse error in googlesheets when using sumifs considering ceratin date range

Tags: date, parsing, range, sumifs

I have made this work already in another googlesheet, which is why I'm puzzled as to why is not working with this one.

I have to sum values from a certain column (`sales`) by month, therefore, checking the date column and grouping it accordingly (summing it).

I guess it has something to do with the date format being used (dd/mm/yy)  but to make sure I used the same parameters I actually put the reference criteria for date within the date column.

```
=sumifs(P9:P12,e9:e12,">="&E9,e9:e12, "<="&E12)
```

I also tried (which works correctlyy in another sheet) adding a separated header column where I set the date parameters (begin and end date), but it didn't work

```
=sumifs($p$378:$p$2000, $e$375:$e$2000,">="&d1, $e$378:$e$2000, "<="&d2)
```

Last but not least, I checked that all dates where equal format by including a cell data validation where the date is actually chosen from a pop up.

Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact problem: A Google Sheets formula working out just fine in one sheet and returning a parse error in a new sheet. The working sheet containing the SUMIF that works is open in one Google account (in Chrome) and apparently used on an American Google Sheet. I copied the working string into a Google Sheet that is apparently a European one (in Firefox) and it returned the parse error.

Turns out, American google sheets uses commas to separate the inputs in a formula, whereas european spreadsheets use a semicolon to separate the inputs.